# How can I disable IDE0002 warning in all projects (not single project) in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I receive from Visual Studio 2017 high number of useless warnings I want to disable some of them in all project. I know how to do it in one project but it is not solution for 50 projects or more.

1. Project
2. Properties
3. Build
4. Errors and warnings
5. Suppress warning

How to do it for all project, whole solution?

How to create some settings file to share such configuration among team?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465181.aspx